# How do I use Ansible's "include_vars" with a GitHub file?

Tags: github, ansible, yaml

I have a YML file stored in a private GitHub repository and am trying to use Ansible's `include_vars` module to upload these variables in the `playbook_dir`.

The tasks responsible for this behavior are all passing however, a later job is failing due to one of the variables being undefined. Which makes me think that I am not correctly adding the values to the directory.

My task.yml file looks like:

```yaml
---
- name: Ensure the application directory exists
  win_file:
    path: '{{ playbook_dir }}'
    state: directory

- name: Download vars file from VCS  
  win_get_url:
    url: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/<org>/<repo>/main/<path-to-file>/DEV1.yml?token=<temp raw file token>'
    dest: '{{ playbook_dir }}/DEV1.yml'
    force: true
  register: result
  
- name: Include vars file for deployment
  include_vars:
    dir: '{{ playbook_dir }}'
    files_matching: DEV1.yml
  register: varfile

- debug: 
    msg: '{{ varfile }}'
```

After running this, the console output for the debug task is:

```
12:35:27  TASK [get_vars : debug] ********************************************************
12:35:27  
12:35:27  {"failed":false,"ansible_included_var_files":[],"ansible_facts":{},"changed":false}
```

Am I not able to download files from GitHub through Ansible?

Comment: The name `vars` is already the name of an Ansible built-in variable. I wonder if that's your problem? Try renaming your variable `vars` to something else. If you still have problems, please add a debug task *after* the `include_vars` that prints out the contents of the registered variable, and include the output in your question.

Comment: Just updated the variable, re-ran, the added the console output of the debug task to the original question. Looks like all of the tasks are still passing, but not actually adding files to the directory. The overall pipeline fail still comes from later tasks trying to use the vars and is the same error message with the var being undefined

Comment: What happens if instead of using `dir` and `files_matching`, you instead use the `file` option of `include_vars` to explicitly load your `DEV1.yml` file?

Comment: Adding the DEV1.yml file directly, which comes from GitHub's raw URL.. i.e.`https://raw.githubusercontent.com/...` now fails within that task saying it can't find or access the given file. I have not been able to find an example of using `include_vars` from a GH file

Comment: It sounds like your `win_get_url` task is either failing or not placing the file where you think it is. If you inspect the contents of your `playbook_dir` directory after running the playbook, does the file exist? I'm not on Windows so I can't use the `win_*` modules, but I put together an equivalent example [here](https://gist.github.com/larsks/af98b4c9faddb838a0717903398a3dbc) and it works just fine, correctly downloading the file and loading it as desired.

Comment: I'm not sure where to inspect the contents of `playbook_dir`. Will that require an additional `debug` task? Also, I see your working example which looks close to identical. Could my issue be that the repo I am trying to access is private?

Comment: "I'm not sure where to inspect the contents of playbook_dir" Just run `ls` in that directory? You may also want to look at the contents of the `result` variable after your "Download vars file from VCS" task to see if it contains any useful status information.

Comment: You can run your ansible with the `-vv` flag to increase the verbosisty, that way you should be able to see more details on your tasks like `win_get_url`